# Filter, Order, export users and groups in Azure under an enterprise application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have created an enterprise application in Azure with custom roles.

Selecting enterprise application > *application* > users and groups we have hadded multiple users against our custom roles.

We cannot see anyway to either filter this list by role / order the list by name / object type / role or even extract this list via csv.

Is there any way to achieve this? any additional permissions that are required?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot achieve this via Azure Portal. You can make use of PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Filter, Order, export users and groups in Azure under an enterprise application, you can make use of PowerShell scripts as it is not possible to do it via Azure Portal.

**To fetch the details of users and groups**:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -searchstring "aadapp-manage" | % {

    $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
  $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }

    Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | % {
    $_ | Add-Member "AppRoleDisplayName" $appRoles[$_.Id] -Passthru
  }
} | ft resourcedisplayname,principaldisplayname, approledisplayname,creationtimestamp
```

[image]

**To filter the list by role, use below script:**

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -searchstring "aadapp-manage" | % {

  $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
  $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }

    Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | % {
    $_ | Add-Member "AppRoleDisplayName" $appRoles[$_.Id] -Passthru
  }
} | Where-Object { $_.AppRoleDisplayName -eq "test.read1" } | ft resourcedisplayname,principaldisplayname, approledisplayname,creationtimestamp
```

[image]

**To order the list by name and get Object type, use below script:**

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -searchstring "aadapp-manage" | % {

  $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
  $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }

  Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | % {

   $principal = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $_.PrincipalId
      
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ResourceDisplayName = $_.ResourceDisplayName
        PrincipalDisplayName = $_.PrincipalDisplayName
        AppRoleDisplayName = $appRoles[$_.Id]
        CreationTimestamp = $_.CreationTimestamp
        PrincipalType = $principal.ObjectType
    }
  }
} | Sort-Object -Property PrincipalDisplayName | ft
```

[image]

**To filter by object type, use below script:**

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -searchstring "aadapp-manage" | % {

  $appRoles = @{ "$([Guid]::Empty.ToString())" = "(default)" }
  $_.AppRoles | % { $appRoles[$_.Id] = $_.DisplayName }

  Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId ($_.ObjectId) | % {

   $principal = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $_.PrincipalId

   # Filter by PrincipalType
   if ($principal.ObjectType -eq "User") {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ResourceDisplayName = $_.ResourceDisplayName
        PrincipalDisplayName = $_.PrincipalDisplayName
        AppRoleDisplayName = $appRoles[$_.Id]
        CreationTimestamp = $_.CreationTimestamp
        PrincipalType = $principal.ObjectType
    }
   }
  }
} | ft
```

[image]

Comment: thank you.   Is there any valid reason why they dont allow this through the interface?